# get href with python using find beautiful soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, location-href

I'm trying to scrape a real estate website, but can't figure out how to get the URL linked to each property.

here's the code I have right now:

I'm still new to coding, I searched other similar topics but couldn't find an answer that would perfectly fit my question.

```py
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

options = Options()
options.add_argument("window-size=1400,600")
from fake_useragent import UserAgent

ua = UserAgent()
a = ua.random
user_agent = ua.random
print(user_agent)
options.add_argument(f'user-agent={user_agent}')

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/raduulea/Documents/chromedriver', options=options)

driver.get('https://www.immoweb.be/fr/recherche/appartement/a-vendre')

import time

time.sleep(10)

Title = []
address = []
price = []
surface = []
desc = []
page = 2
while True:
    time.sleep(10)
    html = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    if int(page) >1:
        results = soup.find_all(True, {"class": ["result-xl", "result-l","result-m"]})
        for result in results:
            Title.append(result.find("div", {"class":"title-bar-left"}).get_text().strip())
            address.append(result.find("span", {"result-adress"}).get_text().strip())
            price.append(result.find("div", {"class": ["xl-price rangePrice", "l-price rangePrice", "m-price rangePrice", "xl-price-promotion rangePrice"]}).get_text().strip())
            surface.append(result.find("div", {"class": ["xl-surface-ch", "l-surface-ch", "m-surface-ch"]}).get_text().strip())
            desc.append(result.find("div", {"class": ["xl-desc", "l-desc", "m-desc"]}).get_text().strip())
        if len(driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("a.next")) > 0:
            url = "https://www.immoweb.be/fr/recherche/appartement/a-vendre/?page={}".format(page)
            driver.get(url)
            page += 1
        else:
            break




df = pd.DataFrame({"Title": Title, "Address": address, "Price:": price, "Surface": surface, "Description": desc})
df.to_csv("immo_a.csv")
```

Here's the Html from where I can get the link:

```html
<a href="https://www.immoweb.be/fr/annonce/immeuble-a-appartements/a-vendre/hoboken/2660/id8135041" title="Immeuble à appartements de 2 façades à vendre à 2660 Hoboken au prix de 545.000 € - (8135041)" target="IWEB_MAIN" xpath="1"></a>
```

Thanks in advance for your help ! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4.element import Tag
import pandas as pd
import traceback
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


options = Options()
options.add_argument("window-size=1400,600")
from fake_useragent import UserAgent

ua = UserAgent()
user_agent = ua.random

options.add_argument(f'user-agent={user_agent}')
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/raduulea/Documents/chromedriver', options=options)

driver.get('https://www.immoweb.be/fr/recherche/appartement/a-vendre')

time.sleep(4)

title = []
address = []
price = []
surface = []
desc = []
link = []

page = 2

try:
    
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
    companies = soup.find("div", {"id": "result"})

    for tag in companies:

        if not isinstance(tag, Tag):
            continue

        _class = tag.get('class')

        if _class is None or "result-xl" not in _class[0]:
            continue

        title.append(tag.find("div", {"class":"title-bar-left"}).get_text().strip())
        address.append(tag.find("span", {"result-adress"}).get_text().strip())
        price.append(tag.find("div", {"class": ["xl-price rangePrice", "l-price rangePrice", "m-price rangePrice", "xl-price-promotion rangePrice"]}).get_text().strip())
        surface.append(tag.find("div", {"class": ["xl-surface-ch", "l-surface-ch", "m-surface-ch"]}).get_text().strip())
        desc.append(tag.find("div", {"class": ["xl-desc", "l-desc", "m-desc"]}).get_text().strip())

        links = tag.find("a",href=True)

        link.append(links['href'])

        if len(driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("a.next")) > 0:
            url = "https://www.immoweb.be/fr/recherche/appartement/a-vendre/?page={}".format(page)
            driver.get(url)
            page += 1
        else:
            break

except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    print(traceback.print_exc())

driver.quit()

df = pd.DataFrame({"Title": title, "Address": address, "Price:": price, "Surface": surface, "Description": desc,"Link":link})
df.to_csv("immo_a.csv")
```

Where

```
links = tag.find("a",href=True)
link.append(links['href'])
```

**Scrape** each property link

csv file o/p:

```
,Title,Address,Price:,Surface,Description,Link
0,Appartement,1090 Jette,"260.000 €  
                                      269.000 €",140 m²     3 ch.,JETTE appartement 2 étages,https://www.immoweb.be/fr/annonce/appartement/a-vendre/jette/1090/id8004072
1,Appartement,6032 Mont-sur-Marchienne,280.000 €,140 m²     4 ch.,Appartement 4 chambres très bien situé,https://www.immoweb.be/fr/annonce/appartement/a-vendre/mont-sur-marchienne/6032/id8137289
2,Appartement,6700 Arlon,210.000 €,110 m²     3 ch.,Appartement spacieux 3 chambres avec garage,https://www.immoweb.be/fr/annonce/appartement/a-vendre/arlon/6700/id8135774
3,Appartement,2000 Anvers,289.000 €,80 m²     1 ch.,Appartement renové avec terrace,https://www.immoweb.be/fr/annonce/appartement/a-vendre/anvers/2000/id8135064
4,Appartement,1200 Woluwe-St-Lambert,"749.000 €  
                                      794.999 €",215 m²     3 ch.,INFOS & VISITE 7/7- SUPERBE DUPLEX PENTHOUSE HOTEL DE MAITRE,https://www.immoweb.be/fr/annonce/appartement/a-vendre/woluwe-st-lambert/1200/id8020453
5,Appartement,9230 Wetteren,199.000 €,95 m²     2 ch.,TOF LICHTRIJK 2-SLKAPPARTEMENT met BALKON in het CENTRUM!,https://www.immoweb.be/fr/annonce/appartement/a-vendre/wetteren/9230/id8134908
6,Duplex,8430 Middelkerke,225.000 €,81 m²     2 ch.,Duplex deux chambres moderne et terrasse,https://www.immoweb.be/fr/annonce/duplex/a-vendre/middelkerke/8430/id8132431
7,Appartement,8400 Ostende,"299.000 €  
                                      320.000 €",80 m²     2 ch.,RESIDENCE OOSTDIJK,https://www.immoweb.be/fr/annonce/appartement/a-vendre/ostende/8400/id6976820
8,Appartement,1000 Bruxelles,450.000 €,121 m²     2 ch.,Appartement ± 135 m² avec terrasse au 4ème étage d'un immeub,https://www.immoweb.be/fr/annonce/appartement/a-vendre/bruxelles/1000/id8132721
9,Penthouse,1180 Uccle,580.000 €,160 m²     2 ch.,Duplex Penthouse avec grande terrasse orientée sud,https://www.immoweb.be/fr/annonce/penthouse/a-vendre/uccle/1180/id8134873
10,Appartement,1050 Ixelles,595.000 €,143 m²     2 ch.,Splendide appartement haut de gamme près du Jardin du Roi,https://www.immoweb.be/fr/annonce/appartement/a-vendre/ixelles/1050/id8134869
11,Appartement,8400 Ostende,"108.000 €  
                                      112.000 €",55 m²     1 ch.,APPARTEMENT DANS UN QUARTIER CALME,https://www.immoweb.be/fr/annonce/appartement/a-vendre/ostende/8400/id8042337
12,Duplex,1180 Uccle,545.000 €,160 m²     4 ch.,Quartier de l'Observatoire DUPLEX-PENTHOUSE 3-4èmes,https://www.immoweb.be/fr/annonce/duplex/a-vendre/uccle/1180/id8131722
13,Appartement,8400 Ostende,185.000 €,75 m²     2 ch.,Appartement,https://www.immoweb.be/fr/annonce/appartement/a-vendre/ostende/8400/id8130087
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand the question correctly below snippets might help you. I am using Beautifulsoup. Here if **IWEB_MAIN** is common attribute.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
data  = ''''<a href="https://www.immoweb.be/fr/annonce/immeuble-a-appartements/a-vendre/hoboken/2660/id8135041" title="Immeuble à appartements de 2 façades à vendre à 2660 Hoboken au prix de 545.000 € - (8135041)" target="IWEB_MAIN" xpath="1"></a>'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
for links in soup.find_all('a',{'target':'IWEB_MAIN'}):
    href = links.get('href')
    title = links.get('title')
    print(href,title)
```